# No Provider for FirebaseApp

Tags: angular, firebase, provider, ionic-native

I am getting this error and there is no solution on the web for this exact error.
 I found answers for “FirebaseAppName” and “AngularFireDatabase” and more, but not for FirebaseApp!

What do I have to install in order to have this provider? I think I installed the latest of angular2 and firebase packages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show some code. Your app.module eg?

Comment: Add FirebaseApp service to your "providers" array in the module or component.

Comment: **I did but it says: Cannot find name 'FirebaseApp'.**

Comment: Did I miss anything?

Comment: I moved to ionic3. the issue no longer exists with my code.